# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' | BeautifulSoup, mistake in parser

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

The mistake:
`token = soup.find("form").find("input").get("value") # type: ignore ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

Code:

```
`import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

link = "https://nz.ua"
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent': user
}

response = session.get(link, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

token = soup.find("form").find("input").get("value")`
```

I am trying to code a parser on the site, but I can`t to run it because that problem

Comment: It's no mistake...you've got Cloudflare captcha page from the server.